# Putting a loop around nested if else statements

Tags: java, loops

I'm sort of new at working with Java. I'm working on a program that takes in student names and their IDs, and when the correct ID is inputted afterwards, it spits out that student's information. The sample output would sort of look like this: How many students would you like to input? (2) What are their names? (Sally, Jack) What are their IDs? (2332, 5631) Would you like to search for a student? (Y) Please input their ID: (2332) We found Sally!

Here is a snippet of the code that searches back for the Student:

```
        System.out.println("Would you like to search for a student?");
        String answer = scan.next();

        if (answer.equals("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an ID:");
            int id = scan.nextInt();
            boolean found = Student.lookupID(list, id);

            if(found)
                System.out.println("Student was found. This student is: " + studentName + ", Student ID " + id); //fix this
            else 
                System.out.println("Error");
        }
        else { 
            System.out.println("Thanks for using this system!");
    }
}
```

}

Right now, I'm trying to loop the code, so that the Output would now look like this: How many students would you like to input? (3) What are their names? (Sally, Jack, Rick) What are their IDs? (2332, 5631, 3005) Would you like to search for a student? (Y) Please input their ID: (2332) We found Sally! Would you like to search for another student? (Y) Please input their ID: (5631) We found Jack! Would you like to search for another student? (N) Thanks for using our system!

Would someone be able to help me with this?

Comment: Your problem is not about Java specifically. What were the obstacles that you had when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset id to program be able to get new id.Try correct your code like this :

```
System.out.println("Would you like to search for a student?");
String answer = scan.next();

int id = 0; //RESET THE ID TO BE ABLE REPLAYIN WORK!
if (answer.equals("Y")) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an ID:");
    id = scan.nextInt();
    boolean found = Student.lookupID(id);

    if (found)
        System.out.println("Student was found. This student is: " + studentName + ", Student ID " + id); // fix
                                                                                                            // this
    else
        System.out.println("Error");
} else {
    System.out.println("Thanks for using this system!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you know how to loop it? I'm trying to use a do while. I'm having trouble with it. @Coder ACJHP

Comment: **use do while statement like this : **`do{//your codes}while(answer.equals("Y"));`**it means as long as the correct answer it will work**